# Runtime of this function: $T(n) = 8T(n/3)+nlogn$

Tags: runtime-analysis

I need to find the runtime of this function:
$$T(n) = 8T(n/3)+nlogn$$

I try to use the "Master Theorem" when
$$a=8,b=3$$
$$n^{log_ba}=n^{log_38}$$
$$f(n)=nlogn$$ 
And I define:
$$\varepsilon = -1.5+log_3 8$$
the first option in "Master Theorem" it`s that (when $\varepsilon >0$):
$$f(n)=nlogn=O(n^{log_3 8-\varepsilon})$$
So:
$$f(n)=nlogn=O(n^{log_3 8-(-1.5+log_3 8)})$$
$$f(n)=nlogn=O(n^{1.5})$$

And its ture! 
So I can say that the runtime it`s:
$$T(n)=\Theta (n^{log_3 8}) $$

That`s true? and why I can say that $\varepsilon=-1.5+log_3 8>0 $ I dont have calculator in the exam!

Thank you for help :)

Comment: You already have a solution to the recurrence and  checking people's answers is off-topic, here. The question about whether $\log_3 8 > 1.5$ is purely a mathematical question with no CS content, so that's off-topic, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to make sure that $\log_{3}8 > 1$ which is easy to see.

Let $\log_3{8} = 1 + \delta$, $\delta > 0$. Set $0 < \epsilon < \delta$. We have $n^{\log_3{8} - \epsilon} > n^1$.

So $n \log n = O(n^{\log_{3}8 - \epsilon})$.